How to set different time intervals for each dashboard chart in Grafana via PostgreSQL queries?
Good afternoon, I have a table in a PostgreSQL database that has a set of data written to it at different intervals.
For example, 10 minutes of data being written to the table, then 8 hours of no data, then again 10 minutes of receiving data, then 13 hours of no data, and again 10 minutes of receiving data.
The thing is, the intervals are always different. I can say for sure that the recording time is always no more than 10 minutes and I know the start and end time of receiving data.
Based on this table I want to create dashboards in grafana and compare visually the last 3 datasets. Is it possible to do this?
Each dataset has its own sequence number in the PostgreSQL table, so the condition in the query can be written like this
SELECT date, data
FROM data_db
WHERE date >= to_timestamp(${__from} / 1000) and date < to_timestamp(${__to} / 1000) AND sessions_num = 2

But this naturally doesn't work because it references the current total value of the interval
I think I need to override $__from and $__to for each chart, but I don't know how to do that.
Also tried changing Relative time and Time shift. That works, but I also need to override those 2 parameters in each query.
Edited:
If I click "Zoom to data", the graph is rearranged
from

to

I would like that with the condition that the intervals between packet sets are always different, I can see these 2 graphs at the same time
The data looks simple. But since there are a lot of them, I insert a small slice:
+-------------------------------------------+
| date                | data | sessions_num |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 2024-07-08 23:55:48 |  0   | 2            |
| 2024-07-08 23:55:48 |  0   | 2            |
| 2024-07-08 23:55:48 |  0   | 2            |
| 2024-07-08 23:55:48 |  0   | 2            |
| 2024-07-08 23:55:48 |  0   | 2            |
| 2024-07-08 23:55:48 |  0   | 2            |
| 2024-07-08 23:55:48 |  0   | 2            |
| 2024-07-08 23:55:48 |  0   | 2            |
| 2024-07-08 23:55:48 |  0   | 2            |
| 2024-07-08 13:10:09 |  0   | 1            |
| 2024-07-08 13:10:09 |  0   | 1            |
| 2024-07-08 13:10:09 |  0   | 1            |
| 2024-07-08 13:10:09 |  0   | 1            |
| 2024-07-08 13:10:09 |  0   | 1            |
| 2024-07-08 13:10:09 |  0   | 1            |
| 2024-07-08 13:10:09 |  0   | 1            |
| 2024-07-08 13:10:10 |  12948 | 1          |
+-------------------------------------------+


I don't get what you have, and what you are trying to achieve exactly. Can you share example of data, and how you invision result?

Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images.

I doubt you can do what you want here. Maybe you can create a variable and specify a relative shift with it, but this will not be trivial.

OTOH, if I were in your place I'd consider displaying all three graphs in the same panel (by manually shifting timestamp)

@markalex, Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately, these offsets will always be different and there is no way to predict what they will be.

Variable can be dynamic. You can create a variable with an SQL query calculating required shift between latest sequence and one before (and second variable for latest and third from end).

@markalex Could you please tell me how to do this? I imagine it like this, I create a variable that calculates the offset, but the problem remains the same - how do I throw this offset through a SQL query?

Sorry, I don't understand your question. Where do you want to "throw this offset through a SQL query"?
